# How can I run 2 google.script.run if condition is met?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

Here's what I'm trying to do: First, if user status in google sheets is now changed from Active to Inactive, and the user is still logged in, he will be then be logged out in case he tries to click any button in the page. In this case, for example the delete (xBtn) button.

**In Js**

```
 //check user status
 function logout_inactive_user(status){
    if (status == "Inactive"){
      logout();
      return;
    } 

     if (status == "Active"){
      return false;   
    } 
}


function retrieve_record(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(display_row).testing_row_data(); 
    }

//show user time log - home page
function display_row(tbl_arr){
    
    //there are some code here to create table

        var xBtn = document.createElement('button')
        xBtn.onclick = function(){

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(logout_inactive_user).check_user_status();
        
        var task_id = number[4];
        const response = confirm("This will delete task " + task_id + ". Proceed?");

        if (response) {
            google.script.run.deleteRows(task_id); 
            tbody.innerHTML = "";
            retrieve_record();
        }
      }
    

}
```

**In Code gs**

```
var the_url = 'the spreadsheet url';   //sheet for code and list of usernames etc
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ts = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var tHs = ss.getSheetByName("User_ID");

function doGet(e) {
    const htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
    return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function testing_row_data(){
    //some code here
    return variable
    
}

function check_user_status(){


  //return user status
  var status_data = tHs.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i<status_data.length;i++){
    if(status_data[i][1] == userEmail){ //[1] because column B
      var u_status = tHs.getRange(i+1,1).getValue() //user status column 1
    }
  }

  return u_status;
}

function deleteRows(task_id) {


  
  var rows = ts.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[4] == task_id) { 
      ts.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }

  

};
```

It doesn't work though. instead of logging out the user, it would still allow user to delete row even if the his status is now Inactive. No error message.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]: 1. Briefly describe the relevant spreadsheet parts 2. Add sample data 3. The server side code should show how the HtmlService is called (it should be clear if this is a Web App, a custom dialog or sidebar) and all the variable declarations (i.e. `tHs` declaration is missing). 3 The client-side thould include the minimal HTML used to call the client-side JavaScript. 5. Describe the code included, what it does, include logs and textual error messages, and the current output and the expected result (the last part is included).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out anyway

```
function testing(){

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(status){

      var yes = "working";
      //alert("checking if inactive");
      if (status == "Inactive"){
        alert("Oops! You no longer have permission to access this page. We will miss you!");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "none";
        
      } else {
        //alert("no");
        google.script.run.alertTask(yes);
        alert("starting task"); 
      }

    }).check_user_status();

}
```